# Generating non-random normally distributed values between two points

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I've stumbled across this code in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15051716/7386609) to a question and I'd like to automate the process of getting the distribution to fit neatly between two bounds.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

bounds = [0, 100]
n = np.mean(bounds)
# your distribution:
distribution = stats.norm(loc=n, scale=20)

# percentile point, the range for the inverse cumulative distribution function:
bounds_for_range = distribution.cdf(bounds)

# Linspace for the inverse cdf:
pp = np.linspace(*bounds_for_range, num=1000)

x = distribution.ppf(pp)

# And just to check that it makes sense you can try:
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.hist(x)
plt.show()
```

Let's say I have the values `[720, 965]`, or any other bounds, that I would like to fit my distribution across. Is there a way to soft-code the adjustment of `scale` in `stats.norm` to fit this distribution across my bounds without any unreasonable gaps? Or are there any functions that have this type of functionality?

A `scale` of ~20 works well for the example code, but I have to adjust it to ~50 for the example of `[720, 965]`

Comment: Is `scale=(bounds[1] - bounds[0]) * 0.2` good enough?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but [truncated normal distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html) should be exactly what you are looking for.

```
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
distr_ab = truncnorm(a, b) # truncated normal distribution in the interval [a, b]
distr_ab.rvs(size=100) # get 100 samples from the distribution
# distr_ab.cdf, distr_ab.ppf etc... all accessible
```