# Speed up drawing random values from superimposed truncated normal distributions

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, normal-distribution, scipy.stats

I want to draw N random samples from a distribution that is the sum of two truncated normal distributions. I get what I want by subclassing `rv_continuous` class from `scipy.stats` and providing a pdf that is the mean of the two given pdfs:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

my_lim = [0.05, 7]  # lower and upper limit
my_loc = [1.2, 3]  # loc values of the two truncated normal distributions
my_scale = [0.6, 2]  # scale values of the two truncated normal distributions

class sum_truncnorm(stats.rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x):
        return (stats.truncnorm.pdf(x,
                                    a=(my_lim[0] - my_loc[0]) / my_scale[0],
                                    b=(my_lim[1] - my_loc[0]) / my_scale[0],
                                    loc=my_loc[0], 
                                    scale=my_scale[0]) + 
                stats.truncnorm.pdf(x,
                                    a=(my_lim[0] - my_loc[1]) / my_scale[1],
                                    b=(my_lim[1] - my_loc[1]) / my_scale[1],
                                    loc=my_loc[1],  
                                    scale=my_scale[1]) / 2
```

However, using:

```py
my_dist = sum_truncnorm()
my_rvs = my_dist.rvs(size=10)
```

is **very** slow and takes about 5 seconds per random value.

I'm sure that this can be done much faster, but I am not sure how to do it. Should I maybe define my distribution as a sum of (non truncated) normal distributions and force the truncated afterwards? I did some tests in this direction, but this was only about 10x faster and thus still way to slow.

Google told me that I probably need to use inverse transform sampling and override the `_rvs` method, but I failed to make this working for my truncated distributions.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll going to have to make sure _pdf is normalized.
The framework does not check it, and silently produces nonsense otherwise.

Second, to make drawing variates fast, you need to implement a _ppf or _rvs. With just _pdf only, it goes through the generic code path (numeric integration and root-finding) which why your current version is slow.

Comment: The _pdf of the two truncnorm should be normalized, no!? As I use the same range for both _pdf and devide the sum of both by 2 I was assuming that it is normalized correctly. Thats not correct? Regarding the implementation of _rvs: thats what I tried but failed to realize.

Comment: I suspect it's easier to write down the _ppf function using https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.ndtri.html

Comment: You use `erf` to get the normalization of a truncated gaussian.